# How to resize image displayed in a table using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, resize

Here is my php that retrieves image from mysql database. I want to resize the image-

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('db', 'table', 'p/w');
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } 
mysql_select_db("db", $con); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM computers WHERE KEYWORDS='Computers'");
echo "<table border='1' width='100%' >"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='folder_name/".$row['image_name']."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Can anyone help ?
thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Resizing images is a well covered topic. Use the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want the images to display at a certain size? Then enter that in the HTML:

```
echo "<td><img src=\"folder_name/{$row['image_name']}\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></td>";
```